# React Native: Run a function in a component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I'm not going to pass data to another component, or access functions from a component and run it in another. Component A takes some data from database. Component B edits some data in Database. When i edit some data in Component B, i need function (fetch data) in component A to be re-executed. i need to update the list in component A.

---

I have a tabbar, one Tab lists data, other tab can edit data. after i edit the data, when i go to first tab, it's still shows the old data. 
One approach could be to re-load the tab every times it's selected.

I'm using react-native-router-flux , but i'm still new to it.

Is it possible? any solutions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
I have few Components. Component A, B and C. actually each component is a tab (TabBar in iOS)

Whenever user makes some changes in Component C, i need to update component A and B.

In component C, when users makes the change, i'm calling Actions.refresh like this :

```js
/// Component C
updated(){
  //// Update database
  Actions.componentA();
  Actions.refresh({somekey: 'True'});
  Actions.componentB();
  Actions.refresh({somekey: 'True'});
  Actions.componentC();
  Actions.refresh({somekey: 'True'});
}
/// So i first call Actions.componentA then i call Actions.refresh to send some props to each component.

/// in each component i added componentwillreceive update. when it receives new props, i'm calling the fetch function again. and setting some random state to make the component reload.

componentWillReceiveProps() {
      this.fetchData();
      this.setState({
        somekey: 'yes'
      });
    }
```